# Completely deleting MacBook Pro hard drive and upgrade to latest OS version

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install, upgrade, secure-erase

I have a High Sierra (10.13.6) MacBook Pro that I purchased back in 2016. Man its been a great machine!

Unfortunately I have beat the heck out of it and made so many systems level changes that its become unusable for me as a developer. I've mainly used it as a testing/experimental sandbox and so my XCode installation is all jacked up, git works in really strange, indecipherable ways, node and npm work very strangely. Maybe if I had **a lot** of spare time I could fix everything, but I don't, and so I'm looking to completely nuke the entire hard drive -- everything -- and install the latest OS version. To reiterate, I want **nothing** (at least in the user space, meaning any files I've created/downloaded) left on the machine. Blank canvas to work with. The goal is nuke the old OS + data, get a new OS and a blank slate to start over with.

So I ask, what are the recommended practices, tools, steps for:

- Deleting everything off the drive (ideally even the OS); and
- Installing whatever is the latest stable version of the MacOS operating system

Ideally -- of course -- it would be great if my purchase of this machine 6 years ago (to the tune of some $2500...) would allow me to get the OS upgrade for free. But if not, c'est la vie. Thanks for any and all help here!

Comment: Please use search before posting. There are many posts on here regarding clean install. Also see [Apple KB - What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) Also, macOS has been free for over a decade - more importantly on an older Mac is just **which** OS it can be updated to. We need to know precisely what Mac to advise on that.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin (+1) -- here are some specs on my Mac: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). If you need more info (to advise) please let me know and I'll add it quickly! Perusing that link you posted, it sounds like I should just be able to delete the OS, turn it back on, and I will see an option to reinstall a new OS?

Comment: Yes, you can always restore a Mac so long as you have an internet connection [that's not a Portal]